# grab category value from mediawiki markup in php

Tags: php, preg-match, mediawiki

I am working on retriving category values from a wiki markup text in loop, could not grab category values from the markup using regex match in php

The Markup Text Contains the category values as

```
$input_wiki_markup = "
[[Category:Google]]
[[Category:Tricks]]
[[Category:Google Search]]
[[Category:Filters]]
[[Category:Search]]
[[Category:Tips]]";
```

Here's what I have tried so far

```
$matches = array();
           if(preg_match("/\[\[(Category):(.+)*\]\]/i", $input_wiki_markup, $matches)){
               print_r($matches);
           }
```

This is the output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => [[Category:Google]][[Category:Tricks]][[Category:Google Search]][[Category:Filters]][[Category:Search]][[Category:Tips]]
    [1] => Category
    [2] => Google]][[Category:Tricks]][[Category:Google Search]][[Category:Filters]][[Category:Search]][[Category:Tips
)
```

But I'm trying to get output array with only category values after colon , i.e.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Google
    [1] => Tricks
    [2] => Google Searcg
)
```

And so on.

What changes should i make to my regex to get only category values filled up in the $mathces array
Or should i use oter php function instead of preg_match ?

Kindly note that, the `$input_wiki_markup` also containes other text around the `[[Categpry:xyz]]` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need was an **all**

```
$input_wiki_markup="
[[Category:Google]]
[[Category:Tricks]]
[[Category:Google Search]]
[[Category:Filters]]
[[Category:Search]]
[[Category:Tips]]
";

$matches = array();
           if(preg_match_all("/\[\[(Category):(.+)*\]\]/i", $input_wiki_markup, $matches)){
               print_r($matches);
           }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => [[Category:Google]]
        [1] => [[Category:Tricks]]
        [2] => [[Category:Google Search]]
        [3] => [[Category:Filters]]
        [4] => [[Category:Search]]
        [5] => [[Category:Tips]]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Category
        [1] => Category
        [2] => Category
        [3] => Category
        [4] => Category
        [5] => Category
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Google
        [1] => Tricks
        [2] => Google Search
        [3] => Filters
        [4] => Search
        [5] => Tips
    )
```

)

Comment: Awesome!! Just prefect solution, just a multi dimensional Array i''ll be looping through to get the values now
Thanks :-)